# Predicting probabilities in R with mixed effects model

Tags: r, binary-data, prediction, mixed-models, multi-level

I have defined a binary response mixed effects model using the R function `glmer` as follows:

```
fit <-glmer(binary_r ~ cat1 + (1 | SUBJECTIDf) + (1 | cat2) + (1 | cat1:cat2), 
                                  family = binomial("logit"), data = mydata))
```

where `cat1` and `cat2` are categorical variables and `SUBJECTIDf` denotes the factor variable tagging the individual subjects of the study. Also, `SUBJECTIDf` and `cat2` are cross-classified factors.

I would like to do the following for the above model:

1. create a table which presents the probability of a positive response for each combination of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2;
2. create a plot (possibly a caterpillar plot) which displays the probabilities defined under a);

and

3. create summary statistics for the probabilities defined under 1., including the minimum and maximum probabilities, across all combinations of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2.

I am assuming that in order to achieve the above outcomes, it would be appropriate to assume that the individual probabilities defined under 1., above are formed as averages or medians across all subjects for a given combination of cat1 and cat2.

I would be most grateful for advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: see `?predict.merMod` (with `type="response"`), `expand.grid` ...

Comment: I am sorry, Ben, that I do not understand how to apply your line of feedback to the specific queries I have raised in order to obtain the particular probabilities and the corresponding graph I have specified. 

In response to cimentadaj, I tried to copy-paste some sample data into the comment field but the structure was mangled on saving, so I have now deleted it and re-sent my comment. Hopefully, someone can provide the code I need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give a reproducible example I'm going to simulate one ... **this part of the answer is only setting up an example data set**.

```
## crossed cat2 and SUBJECTIDf
dd <- expand.grid(cat2=factor(letters[1:10]),
                  SUBJECTIDf=factor(1:10))
## each subject gets one value of cat1:
## for example, half get A while half get B
cat_tab <- data.frame(SUBJECTIDf=factor(1:10),cat1=rep(c("A","B"),5))
dd <- merge(dd,cat_tab)
```

I'm having a little trouble accommodating the design consideration that `cat1` and `cat2` are not cross-classified.  I'll just knock out some categories:

```
dd <- with(dd,dd[!(cat1=="A" & cat2 %in% c("a","b","c")),])
```

Now we have the design set up, we simulate response values:

```
library(lme4)
form <- binary_r ~ cat1 + (1 | SUBJECTIDf) + (1 | cat2) + (1 | cat1:cat2)
dd$binary_r <- simulate(form[-2],  ## RHS only
         family=binomial,
         newdata=dd,
         newparams=list(beta=0:1,
                        theta=c(2,4,1)),
         seed=101)[[1]]
```

At this point we come in with the model fit you've suggested above.

```
fit <- glmer(form, family = binomial, data=dd)
```

> create a table which presents the probability of a positive response for each combination of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2;

By setting `re.form` below to exclude subject ID, we are implicitly computing the value for the *hypothetical* median individual (i.e., random effect set to zero; mean and median predictions coincide on the logit scale, but not once we back-transform to the probability scale).

Get unique combinations of `cat1` and `cat2` found in the data:

```
newdd <- unique(dd[,c("cat1","cat2")])
newdd$SUBJECTIDf <- NA  ## need to have SUBJECTIDf in the data frame ...
t1 <- predict(fit,newdata=newdd,type="response",
              re.form=~(1|cat2)+(1|cat1:cat2))
newdd <- data.frame(newdd[,c("cat1","cat2")],pred=t1)
head(newdd)
##   cat1 cat2        pred
## 4    A    d 0.215336024
## 5    A    e 0.944897414
## 6    A    f 0.036751551
## 7    A    g 0.003819873
## 8    A    h 0.970115614
## 9    A    i 0.003819873
```

We could also compute predictions for all individuals as follows:

```
## we happen to have a factorial design, but expand.grid() would
## e.g. fill in missing values
newdd2 <- unique(dd[,c("cat1","cat2","SUBJECTIDf")])
t2 <- predict(fit,newdata=newdd2,type="response",
              re.form=NULL)
newdd2$pred <- t2
head(newdd2)
```

In order to create the plot (see below) we would have to summarize across individuals within category combinations.

> create a plot (possibly a caterpillar plot) which displays the probabilities defined under a);

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(newdd,aes(cat2,pred,colour=cat1))+
   geom_point()+scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Or, aggregating the subject-specific predictions:

```
ggplot(newdd2,aes(cat2,pred,colour=cat1))+
   stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point")+
   scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

We could use `reorder()` on the `cat2` categories to try to get a more sensible order, but since there is a `cat1:cat2` interaction, that might not work too well.  Caterpillar plots (i.e. getting uncertainties on predictions) are a little trickier, because of the difficulty of getting uncertainty on predictions that combine uncertainty in conditional modes (values of individual random effects) and fixed effects.  Can be done by (1) assuming conditional modes and fixed effects are independent or (2) parametric bootstrapping (`bootMer`), but both are a little more trouble than I'm willing to take at the moment ...

> create summary statistics for the probabilities defined under 1., including the minimum and maximum probabilities, across all combinations of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2.

This doesn't really make sense to me unless we are going the disaggregated route.  If we have predicted for each combination of `cat1` and `cat2`, then we only have a single value for each combination (i.e., no "min/max" probabilities). Aggregating is easy in base R, e.g.

```
 aggregate(pred~cat1:cat2,data=newdd2,
            FUN=function(x) c(min=min(x),max=max(x)))
```

or in the tidyverse:

```
 library(dplyr)
 newdd2 %>% group_by(cat1,cat2) %>%
     summarise(min=min(pred),max=max(pred))
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind input, Ben. For my dataset, only cat2 and SUBJECTIDf are cross-classified, while one and one only category from cat1 is assigned to each member of SUBJECTIDf. Can your code for expand.grid be modified to reflect this fact so as to avoid a full factorial design?

Comment: Also, as all of the variables I list under glmer are already captured within a dataframe, mydata, why is it necessary for me to redefine them?

Comment: In addition, I am sorry that I do not understand what the code dd$binary_r <- simulate(form[-2],  ## RHS only
         family=binomial,
         newdata=dd,
         newparams=list(beta=0:2,
                        theta=c(2,4,1))
is need for. Can you please explain what it achieves.

Comment: Ben, while waiting to hear back from you, I have tried to implement your recommended code, including the code I have queried in my third comment above, while adapting it to the variables I have. The code I have queried has generated the following error message: 'Error in model.frame.default(data=newdata, weights=weights,offset=offset,: variable lengths differ (found for SUBJECTIDf" In addition: Warning message: 'newdata' had 87048 rows but variables found have 279 rows'. Can somebody help, please? In my first comment, I have explained the nature of the crossed design.

Comment: I understand that my wording "create a table which presents the probability of a positive response for each combination of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2" under my first query (1., above) could have been clearer as "for each combination of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2" should read "for each combination of categories pertaining to cat1 and cat2 which are actually realized by the response data". (Not all combinations are necessarily realized as cat1 and cat2 are not cross-classified.)  I hope that this helps and I am sorry if I caused any misunderstanding.